# How to check user input if 1st and 3rd digit are equal

Tags: javascript

I want to check the first and third digit from a user input and also whether the second digit is different from the other two, e.g.: 676.

```
function myfunction()

{
  var formvalid = true;
 var x=document.forms["form1"]["input_text"].value;
   if (isNaN(x)) 
  {
    alert("Must input numbers");
    formvalid = false;
  }
   var a=document.getElementById("in_num").value;
   if(a.length < 3 || a.length >3)
    {
  alert("input 3 digit number");
      formvalid= false;
}
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="form1" >
<input type="text" id="in_num"  name="input_text"/> 
<input type="button" id="but_id" value="submit" onclick="myfunction();" />
 </form>
```

Comment: so you are almost there, what is the trouble?

Comment: first num i can get by (num/100), 3rd num  (num%10) and middle num (sum of num-2*1st num).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkNumber(n) {
    if(n > 999 || n < 100) {
        return false;
    }

    var n1 = Math.floor(n/100)
    var n2 = Math.floor((n/10)%10)
    var n3 = Math.floor(n%10)

    return (n1 === n3 && n1 !== n2)
}

checknumber(676)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use number%10 and number/10 to get the individual numbers and then from there its a simple if-else construct

```
number = 676;

var ones = 676%10  // Here ones = 6
var remaining = 676/10 // remaining = 67

var tens = remaining%10;
remaining = remaining/10;
var hundreds = remaining%10;
remaining = remaining/10;
```

Now you have ones, tens and hundreds variable you can check for the required condition.